Visual comparison difference between headed and headless playwright test
I have a test that does visual comparison on a profile picture.
If i run the test in headless mode, the picture will be generated on first attempt and then always pass, same happens if i run the test in --ui mode
If i run the test in headed mode the test will always fail with the following error:
Expected an image 104px by 105px, received 105px by 104px.

If i delete the visual comparison photos and run the test that first generates the photos in headed mode, the headless tests will fail with the same error. What solution would i have for this and how would i implement it ?
If i use setViewportSize, how should it look like ? I have this but for now it doesn't work
await functions.locatorVisualAssertion(page.setViewportSize({ width: 100, height: 100 }),'div[role^="presentation"]',-1, 'firstphoto.png');


Can you share a runnable [mcve] so there's something to work off of here? How can I reproduce this behavior? Thanks.
